# What is the cause of this strange error message in Google's Cloud Datalab when importing cv2

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I have the following code in a Datalab notebook:

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
```

Seems pretty straight forward.

But when I run it, it crashes giving the following error:

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-22ccccfbcefe> in <module>()
      2 import glob
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import cv2
      5 from sklearn.utils import shuffle
      6 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
      6 
----> 7 from . import cv2
      8 sys.modules['cv2'] = cv2

ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. I have opencv installed via pip but this still happens. Any ideas??

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Had to run the following:

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get -y upgrade
!pip install opencv-python
!apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev -y
```